# Does Mountain Lion support Canon Pixma printers?

Tags: macos, printing, driver, canon

I've recently re-installed Mountain Lion after I upgraded from Lion on a 2009 iMac.
Before the reinstallation, my printer, a Canon Pixma iP3000, worked perfectly and out of the box — no drivers to install, supported by the OS.

Now, instead, my Mac doesn't have Canon drivers at all, and I can't find any on the internet.

How do I use my printer with my Mac?

---

```
Model Name: iMac
Model Identifier:   iMac10,1

CUPS Version:   1.6.2 (cups-327.6)

System Version: OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Kernel Version: Darwin 12.4.0
```

This is what the OS sees of the printer (it's just USB data):

```
iP3000:

Product ID: 0x1094
Vendor ID:  0x04a9  (Canon Inc.)
Version:     1.10
Serial Number:  A4319B
Speed:  Up to 12 Mb/sec
Manufacturer:   Canon
Location ID:    0x06400000 / 3
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA):  2
1284 Device ID: MFG:Canon;CMD:BJL,BJRaster3,BSCCe;SOJ:TXT01;MDL:iP3000;
                CLS:PRINTER;DES:Canon iP3000;VER:1.10;STA:20;FSI:03;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has moved the printer drivers out of the OS and made them available on a separate page. Very unfortunately they don't mention the exact printer models, nor that the pacakge is for Snow Leopard on the page so they are hard to find with Google.

> Canon Inkjet Printer Drivers v2.12 for OS X

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl899

Comment: The typical manner for print drivers on OS X (Mountain Lion included) is now to power on the printer and plug it in. The OS will select and download the drivers as needed and from that point forward, software update will keep your drivers updated. It's not wrong to download the drivers from the website, but it's not the normal / preferred way. Odd that your Mac didn't prompt you to install the correct driver.

Answer (score 0):

The [canon drivers](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl899) for apple also work for the Canon Pixma ip1700, and likely also other Canon Pixma drivers. The ip1700 isn't listed in the official list of printers supported by this download, but if you tell your mac the printer is an ip1800 then it seems to work fine.